# delete uploaded file

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I have a function wp_handle_upload() for uploads files.

```
$file = $_FILES['attachment_icon-' . $i];
$upload = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
```

what is a function for delete a uploaded file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `unlink()` to delete a file.

`unlink('/path/to/file');`

Comment: If the file as been attached to a specific post you should use `wp_delete_attachment()`, cause using the above will leave dead entries in your database.